# Show GridView images from JSON Android

Tags: java, android, json, gridview, android-gridview

I have a problem when displaying images from JSON to GridView could help me .

GalleryActivity.java

```
public class GalleryActivity extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.gallery_layout);

         Intent i = getIntent();

         String tempid = i.getStringExtra("tempid");

        GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);


        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this,tempid));


        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

ImageAdapter.java

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public String[] mThumbIds;

    private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";

    private static String KEY_IMAGES = "images";
    private static String KEY_IMAGE = "url_img";


    // Constructor
    public ImageAdapter(Context c,String tempID){
        mContext = c;
         final DealerFunctions dealerFunction = new DealerFunctions();
         JSONObject json = dealerFunction.getImages(tempID);

         try {

                if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {

                    String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                    if (Integer.parseInt(res) == 1) {


                        JSONArray imagesFields = json
                                .getJSONArray(KEY_IMAGES);


                        for (int i = 0; i < imagesFields.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject x = imagesFields.getJSONObject(i);

                            mThumbIds[i] =  x.getString(KEY_IMAGE);


                        }



                    } else {


                    }

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }


    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }


    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mThumbIds[position];
    }


    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }


    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {         
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView==null){

            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
             imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
             imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70));

        }else{
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(mThumbIds[position]));

        return imageView;
    }

}
```

Don't Work...

when I run the application, closes immediately assume that the problem comes in imageView.setBackgroundDrawable (Drawable.createFromPath (mThumbIds [position]));

I need your help guys

Logcat Errors as follows.

```
03-27 10:50:12.658: D/AndroidRuntime(1782): Shutting down VM
03-27 10:50:12.658: W/dalvikvm(1782): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
03-27 10:50:12.678: E/AndroidRuntime(1782): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-27 10:50:12.678: E/AndroidRuntime(1782): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.montalvo.dealer/com.montalvo.dealer.GalleryActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-27 10:50:12.678: E/AndroidRuntime(1782):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
03-27 10:50:12.678: E/AndroidRuntime(1782):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
03-27 10:50:12.678: E/AndroidRuntime(1782):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
03-27 10:50:12.678: E/AndroidRuntime(1782):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
03-27 10:50:12.678: E/AndroidRuntime(1782):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-27 10:50:12.678: E/AndroidRuntime(1782):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-27 10:50:12.678: E/AndroidRuntime(1782):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-27 10:50:12.678: E/AndroidRuntime(1782):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-27 10:50:12.678: E/AndroidRuntime(1782):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-27 10:50:12.678: E/AndroidRuntime(1782):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-27 10:50:12.678: E/AndroidRuntime(1782):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-27 10:50:12.678: E/AndroidRuntime(1782):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-27 10:50:12.678: E/AndroidRuntime(1782): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-27 10:50:12.678: E/AndroidRuntime(1782):     at com.montalvo.dealer.ImageAdapter.<init>(ImageAdapter.java:57)
03-27 10:50:12.678: E/AndroidRuntime(1782):     at com.montalvo.dealer.GalleryActivity.onCreate(GalleryActivity.java:25)
03-27 10:50:12.678: E/AndroidRuntime(1782):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-27 10:50:12.678: E/AndroidRuntime(1782):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
03-27 10:50:12.678: E/AndroidRuntime(1782):     ... 11 more
03-27 10:50:15.501: I/Process(1782): Sending signal. PID: 1782 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing things up here, use this

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {         
    ImageView imageView;
    imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70));


    imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(mThumbIds[position]));

    return imageView;
}
```

The pattern you have used is that of the ViewHolder but you are not creating any views. If you do want to use the ViewHolder model then,

1. first create an xml with an ImageView.
2. Create a ViewHolder class in your ImageAdapter with an ImageView.
3. In the getView() method, inflate the xml.
4. create the viewholder for the case of convertview == null
5. set the viewholder as the TAG of the convertview.
6. in the else condtion, assign the previously created viewholder to the convertview.

Comment: you can place the code to better understand the viewHolder, thanks a lot.